# How to hide password without changing the format of input box?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm designing a login webpage and it looks like this:
[image]

where the '123456' is the password.

However, when I tried to hide the password by changing my code as:

```
<input Name="Password" type="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" required="">
```

the input box for password became this:

[image]

So are there any ways to hide the password but keep the format of inputting text box?

Here's my source code:

```
<form action="login_singletest.php" method="post">

                <div class="w3_cc">

                </div>
                    <input type="text" class="margin-right" Name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                    <input Name="Password" type="text" id="Password" placeholder="Password" required="">

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="send-button agileits w3layouts">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Log In </button>
                    </div>
                 </form>
```

Comment: check your stylesheet/elements. You should include any css you may have for this.

Comment: Are you sure you only changed the ```type``` attribute?

Comment: @surge10 Yes, I changed only the type.

Comment: You didn't change only the type, Answer below says you changed the class as well.

Comment: apply the same style you applied to the other input

Comment: @surge10 No. The answer below doesn't work. Maybe I should check the css.

Comment: [Right..., like I said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092267/how-to-hide-password-without-changing-the-format-of-input-box#comment87200795_50092267) but you rather respond to others instead of having some get downvoted because of you and not commenting under the answer. Well, I'm out. Btw, that wasn't my downvote for the answer (by blackers).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry, I know nothing about css and I was trying to find out which css is working on the style. It took me a while.

Comment: I've been doing html/css far before php. I'm not a css guru but I know my way around quite well (not throwing myself flowers here). If there's a rule that is overriding it and one such as bootstrap for example, then you'll need to add the `!important` rule to the given element. Now by "it took me a while", I take it that you've solved it? @Yujian

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Actually I didn't solve it. I'm still inspecting the code...

Comment: if you happen to solve it yourself and that nobody else found the solution before you and you see their answer(s), you can post your own solution; Stack lets you do that. You can then accept your answer when it lets you.

Comment: one thing you can do is to use the developer's console and tool section to select the input and see which rule (and in which file) controls it. And apply that same style to it. There could be something overriding it also.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you for the advice! I'll try it. Can I ask you if I fail? It may take some time.

Comment: btw, any javascript being used here? It's hard to say if that when you enter a password it is shown but then wanting to hide it. The question for me is unclear. You would need to post a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ for this, then update your post should this be the case. Other than that, I can't help you.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No Javescript here. And after careful inspection, I found that the "password" box did have two css styles missing when compared to "Email" box. I tried the jsfiddle, but not that sure whether I uploaded the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="email" class="margin-right" Name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="password" class="margin-right" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

My apology. My classmate passed me the wrong css file in which she didn't define "type = password". Now everything's settled after the css file was modified. @FunkFortyNiner Thank you very much for being so patient.